# Connecting to Postgres Via database_url and Unix Socket in Rails

Tags: rails-activerecord

I've hunted around for this and just can't find a solution.

Currently I have a database.yml connected to a local pgbouncer server on a Unix socket successfully. However, I'm transitioning to setting this to a database_url environment variable and cannot work out at all how to connect to a local Postgres server via a Unix socket. localhost obviously works OK.

I was looking at a URL that looks like this as apparently you can use this with Postgres (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/libpq-connect.html):

```
export DATABASE_URL="postgresql://username@%Fvar%Frun%Fpostgresql%F.s.PGSQL.6432/dbname"
```

However, this will not get past the URI police:

```
rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): postgresql://username@%Fvar%Frun%Fpostgresql%F.s.PGSQL.6432/dbname
```

Does anyone have any idea about the secret sauce needed for this? I've Googles endlessly and haven't found anything. It must be possible since the application currently connects over a socket now.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 29):

> **[31.1.1.2. Connection URIs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-connect.html)**
>
> The general form for a connection URI is:
>
> ```
> postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]`
> ```
>
> The URI scheme designator can be either postgresql:// or postgres://.
>   Each of the URI parts is optional. The following examples illustrate
>   valid URI syntax uses:
>
> ```
> postgresql://
> postgresql://localhost
> postgresql://localhost:5433
> postgresql://localhost/mydb 
> postgresql://user@localhost
> postgresql://user:secret@localhost
> postgresql://other@localhost/otherdb?connect_timeout=10&application_name=myapp
> ```
>
> Components of the hierarchical part of the URI can also be given as
>   parameters. For example:
>
> ```
> postgresql:///mydb?host=localhost&port=5433
> ```
>
> Percent-encoding may be used to include symbols with special meaning
>   in any of the URI parts.
>
> Any connection parameters not corresponding to key words listed in
>   Section 31.1.2 are ignored and a warning message about them is sent to
>   stderr.
>
> For improved compatibility with JDBC connection URIs, instances of
>   parameter `ssl=true` are translated into `sslmode=require`.
>
> The host part may be either host name or an IP address. To specify an
>   IPv6 host address, enclose it in square brackets:
>
> ```
> postgresql://[2001:db8::1234]/database
> ```
>
> The host component is interpreted as described for the parameter host.
>   In particular, a Unix-domain socket connection is chosen if the host
>   part is either empty or starts with a slash, otherwise a TCP/IP
>   connection is initiated. Note, however, that the slash is a reserved
>   character in the hierarchical part of the URI. **So, to specify a**
>   **non-standard Unix-domain socket directory, either omit the host**
>   **specification in the URI and specify the host as a parameter, or**
>   **percent-encode the path in the host component of the URI:**
>
> ```
> postgresql:///dbname?host=/var/lib/postgresql
>
> postgresql://%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fpostgresql/dbname
> ```

Comment: localhost connects via TCP/IP (127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::1%lo0, etc). To use the Unix Socket like OP asked omit the host.

Comment: Lies lies! I am using `postgresql://user:pass/dbname` to no avail. I've tried many variations of the above. Seems to be rails 3.2.21. I get no meaningful error message from the application (openproject), but the tcp form at least logs an auth error with pg. @J.Money

Comment: @Otheus My comment was about using localhost in the connection string. Since localhost is not empty and does not start with a slash it is interpreted as a host name and connects to the loopback connection via TCP/IP. "A Unix-domain socket connection is chosen if the host part is either empty or starts with a slash" so you still need to specify the host for non-standard sockets. Do you have the following in your database.yml file: `host: /path/to/socket/file`

Comment: @J.Money Correct, but omitting the host does not work -- but this is not because of `libpq`. Apparently activerecord (3.2.21) is doing something magical here. It tries to parse the string on its own via `URI.parse` instead of passing it to `PGconn`. :(

Comment: The last option, but changing `lib` to `run` worked for me: `postgresql://%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fpostgresql/dbname`. The docs also have some good information about connection precedence: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference

Comment: rather than copy the manual page into an answer, try phrasing the answer in just a few words. after which, you can link to the documentation.

Answer (score 25):

You must omit the host to use unix socket, like so:

```
postgres://username@/dbname
```

or simply

```
postgres:///dbname
```

This works with psql > 9.2.

I am not sure it works with the rails handling of the database URL.

Comment: This does not work with Rails 4.2.5 and PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Although seemingly unrelated, I was missing the third slash on my app that I was porting to Rails 5... And that solved [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320772/runtimeerror-cant-modify-frozen-array-when-running-rspec-in-rails-5-1) issue I was experiencing.

Comment: interesting, adding ? you can add parameters like sslmode=disable 
postgres:///dbname?ssmode=disable

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @blnc is correct if using `libpq` in general. However, if you are using Activerecord or RubyonRails, at least in version `3.2.21`, that module parses the URI to Ruby's `URI.parse`, instead of directly handing it to libpq. URI.parse cannot handle an empty hostname here.

```
irb(main):020:0> URI.parse "postgresql://user:pass@host/dbname"
=> #<URI::Generic:0x7f72b17f04d8 URL:postgresql://user:pass@host/dbname>
```

But, without host:

```
irb(main):021:0> URI.parse "postgresql://user:pass@/dbname"
URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme postgresql does not accept registry part: user:pass@ (or bad hostname?)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/generic.rb:195:in `initialize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:492:in `new'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:492:in `parse'
        from (irb):21
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/generic.rb:556
```

There appears to be no way to fix this without adding custom URI-parsing code (or altering activerecord).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the socket as a query parameter:

```
postgresql://user@host/database?socket=/path/to/socket
```

Comment: socket is not a valid parameter for most PostgreSQL API

Answer (score 1):

On Archlinux with default path for `unix_socket_directories`:

```
postgres:///<dbname>?host=/run/postgresql/
```