# Sequelize-cli migration with non-standard unix sockets

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm trying to get sequelize going on GAE. But am struggling with the cloud SQL proxy that uses sockets on non-standard paths.

My understanding is that a url would get passed direct to the pg library, and based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037990/connecting-to-postgres-via-database-url-and-unix-socket-in-rails), it would suggest the below string is what I need

I've setup the db configuration to be

```
{
  url: 'postgresql:///db_user:db_password@/db_name?host=./cloudsql/my-project-1234:us-central1:my-cloud-sql-instance', 
  dialect: 'postgres'
}
```

However, if I run `./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate` I end up with the error:

```
ERROR: database "db_user:db_password@/db_name" does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, it is possible to pass the socket path using the host variable, but there are a few gotcha's:

1. The path **must** be absolute, that is, it must start with a `/` (otherwise it assumes it is a hostname)
2. [The socket path must be 108 characters or less on a Linux-based operating system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html). If I placed the socket in a subfolder with my project (which was in my home directory), I got `ENOENT` (file not found), but moving the sockets to `/cloudsql` in the root path fixed it.
3. It will assume that path is the directory and append `/.s.PGSQL.5432` to that (which is fine because Google's SQL proxy socket is in that file)

So with the following config, I was able to run a database migration through google's cloud SQL proxy:

```
{
    username: 'my_user',
    password: 'my_password',
    database: 'my_database',
    host: `/cloudsql/my-app-12345:us-central1:my_database`,
    logging: false,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    // Google cloud_sql_proxy is encrypted, so no need to encrypt
    ssl: false,
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: false,
    },
    operatorsAliases: false,
}
```

Comment: spent a hell lot of time trying to figure this out! And in the end I found your Github issue and this SO post... I also came to the same solution... hope I would have seen this earlier ;P would have saved me a lot of time and trouble.... Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this! Worked when I deployed